# Issue with VSC build (CMD-Shift-B) command on mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working through the instructions on building VSC for developers (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run) currently.  Right under "Build" it instructs me to go "Go into vscode and start the build task with CMD+Shift+B) since I have a mac.  I have gone into the folder in my finder and have pressed this combination of buttons but nothing happens at all.  Am I supposed to do this in the terminal or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `vscode` directory must be opened in Visual Studio Code and a build is performed with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Here is an older version of the instructions where it is clearer:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-wiki/blob/2e2d6b0/How-to-Contribute.md#build

It appears that the directory `vscode` got mixed up with the full application name in a subsequent edit.